# Do I need to purchase the Online Pass even though I bought it new?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

When I went to check out the co-op play option but it says that I haven't purchased the Online Pass and therefore cannot use it. I know that online passes have become more popular in the past year and often require a separate purchase if you buy the game used/secondhand, but so far the precedent I have seen is that you get an online pass if you purchase new.

I have purchased Saints Row: The Third brand new (the Platinum Pack even). It didn't seem to come with any separate Online Pass code that I can find in my box. All I had was the code for the Professor Genki DLC.

Do I have to purchase the Online Code separately even though I have a new version of the game? Is it possible my box was just missing the code?

Comment: I don't have it, but any game like this, it should be included in the box with the game. You didn't happen to buy it from a GameStop-like-shop did you, where it was opened, but new?

Comment: A post on their site about this should be [included in the box](http://www.saintsrow.com/news/detail/article/251863/online_pass_notification). Can't tell if this means the DLC includes it or not. Dumb question, but did you check the other side of the paper with the code? I've seen 2 codes on one piece of paper before in games.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you shouldn't need to purchase the Online Pass if you bought the game new. A [post on the official site](http://www.saintsrow.com/news/detail/article/251863/online_pass_notification) confirms that the Online Pass should be included with any new game.

> Inside your copies of the game will be a code to enter on your console
>   in order to play Co-Op with a friend.

Either:

- The code is in there, and you haven't found it. Check the back-side of any papers, manual, or the fold out instruction booklet.
- The code is bundled with the DLC pack (can't tell from wording on the above post).
- The code is not in your box for some reason, in which case, I guess you should contact Volition, or the store you purchased it from.

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks, this was a case of me just being silly and then panicking. :P The instruction booklet wasn't an actual booklet, it's a fold out piece of paper sort of like a pamphlet, and I accidentally missed it.